# Consensus roles for op_return

Tags: consensus, validation, op-return

What is the validation rule, not policy, for op_return? What is the maximum length of the data that can be attached? Is it 514 bytes? As if the maximum script size was 520 bytes -1 byte for the instruction itself and -3 bytes for push instruction? Also is it possible to have more instructions after op_return, not just one push?

Comment: IMO 520 is for the push data (excluding the OP_PUSHDATA and its size).

Comment: Does it mean I could have 10 pushes in one output and one op_return with total of 5 kB?

Answer (score 1):

- Each scriptPubKey is limited to 10000 bytes.
- Each individual push in a scriptPubKey is limited to 520 bytes.
- Transactions are limited by the block weight limit.

Comment: thank you, so just to make sure I understand correctly - does it mean I could have 10 pushes (520 each) in one output and one op_return with total of >5 kB? and does 520 includes op code itself or is 520 just raw data?